# Print alphabet with Number

Tags: c#

i have code like this :

```
static string[] numStr = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };
    static string[] alphaStr = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Z" };

private static void Quiz_2()
    {
        for (int w = 0; w < alphaStr.Length; w++)
        {
            for (int v = 0; v < alphaStr.Length; v++)
            {
                for (int u = 0; u < alphaStr.Length; u++)
                {
                    for (int t = 0; t < alphaStr.Length; t++)
                    {
                        for (int s = 0; s < alphaStr.Length; s++)
                        {
                            for (int r = 0; r < alphaStr.Length; r++)
                            {
                                for (int o = 0; o < alphaStr.Length; o++)
                                {
                                    for (int n = 0; n < alphaStr.Length; n++)
                                    {
                                        for (int m = 0; m < alphaStr.Length; m++)
                                        {
                                            for (int i = 0; i < alphaStr.Length; i++)
                                            {
                                                for (int j = 0; j < numStr.Length; j++)
                                                {
                                                    for (int k = 0; k < numStr.Length; k++)
                                                    {
                                                        for (int l = 0; l < numStr.Length; l++)
                                                        {
                                                            Console.Write(alphaStr[w] + alphaStr[v] + alphaStr[u] + alphaStr[t] + alphaStr[s] + alphaStr[r] + alphaStr[o] + alphaStr[n] + alphaStr[m] + alphaStr[i] + numStr[j] + numStr[k] + numStr[l] + " ");
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

if i run my program, result are shown like this :
AAAAAAAAAA000
..
AAAAAAAAAA999
AAAAAAAAAB000
..
AAAAAAAAAB999
AAAAAAAAAC000
AAAAAAAAAC001

My expected result :

AAAAAAAAAA000
..
AAAAAAAAAA999
AAAAAAAAAB000
..
AAAAAAAAAB999
AAAAAAAABB000
AAAAAAAABB001

anyone can help me ?

Comment: What is the logic behind this?

Comment: See [Arrow Code](https://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/)

Comment: What is this madness?!

Answer (score 1):

Use recursion :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Recursive(0, "");
        }
        static void Recursive(int index, string str)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < characters.Length; i++)
            {
                string newStr = str + characters[i];
                if (index == 12)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(newStr);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                else
                {
                    Recursive(index + 1, newStr);
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're better of writing a single for loop and adding some logic.

Here's what I mean:

```
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       string s = "AAAAAAAAAAAA";
       for(int i=0; i<s.Length; i++)
       {             
         for(int j=0; j<=999; j++)
         {
           (s + j.ToString("D3")).Dump();
         }

         //And now do some logic to increment the string
         //I'm not 100% sure what you want, maybe something like this?
         //First char = 'A'. Find the last char in the string <> 'A' and change it to 'A'+1
         //If none are found, all chars are the same, last char++
       }
    }
}
```